# Alignment of Collapsible div's in an HTML page

Tags: css, list, layout, html, expandable

I'm hoping someone can help me with collapsible `div` tags.

What I want to do is to create a list with multiple collapsible 2-column sections. The sections are designed with `div` tags and embedded into a list.

My code so far works in IE, but not in Firefox or Chrome. In the latter two, the list items move to the right when a 2-column sample is expanded.

The code below reproduces the problem. If you open it in Mozilla or Chrome and click on the `[ ]` in the first sample item, the bullet item for the sample below will move to the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>  
<style type="text/css">
div.sample {
position:relative;
left:0px;
}  
div.item {
position:relative;
display:none;
width:600px;
left:10px;
text-align:justify;
}

div.ltcol{
float:left;
width:45%;
}

div.rtcol{
float:right;
width:45%;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li><div id="sample1" class="sample">Sample <a href="#" OnClick="showone('verbiage1');">[&nbsp;]</a>
<div id="verbiage1" class="item">
<div id="source" class="ltcol">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div id="target" class="rtcol">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div></div></li>

<li><div id="sample2" class="sample">Sample <a href="#" OnClick="showone('verbiage2');">[&nbsp;]</a>
<div id="verbiage2" class="item">
<div id="source" class="ltcol">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div id="target" class="rtcol">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div></div></li>

<script>
//Quick and dirty javascript to get it up and running.
alldivs=['verbiage1','verbiage2'];

function showone(name) {
 divname="#".concat(name);
for (var i in alldivs){
if ("#".concat(alldivs[i])==divname){
   $(("#".concat(alldivs[i]))).toggle(200);
  }
  else{
      $(("#".concat(alldivs[i]))).hide(200);
  }
 }
  return true;
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly you need to clear your verbiage div's. See this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/Ujw5b/

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
   display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
   display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
   height: 1%;
   overflow: visible;
}
```